# provide full file path on d3.js ejs template

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, d3.js

I'm using `d3.js` on my `ejs` template in a `node.js` project. I'm generating a `csv` file from backend and using this `csv` file on `d3.js` for visualization on `ejs` template. But when i'm trying to read the file as:

```
d3.csv("myfile.csv", function(d) {
  console.log(d)
  d.value = +d.number;
  if (d.value) return d;
  }, function(error, classes) {
  if (error) throw error;
 }
 //other tasks
});
```

My code is throwing `404` error as `http://localhost:3000/myfile.csv 404 (Not Found)`. Could anyone please provide me any idea to read the file path.

Comment: In this case myfile.csv should be in same directory as app.js

Comment: it is in the same directory :/

Comment: What way is node serving your static files?